# How to validate form data entry before navigation with WinForms in .NET using DataBindingNavigator?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, validation

I'm just starting on .NET development with C#.  Although I'm getting comfortable with the language itself I need some help with the peculiarities of the framework.

I'm building a windows forms application to replace a simple Access database.  I have the data source connected, dropped controls on the form, put the basic logic in place, no problems there.  Even figured out that I need to manually save the data back to the database using tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(...) or similar.

My current problem, which I've been unable to find a resolution to after much googling, is how to validate my data entry before allowing the user to leave the current record.

Scenario:

User clicks 'Add' to get a new record, fills in some of the data but doesn't fill in one of the required fields.  User then navigates to a different record without hitting the 'Save' button.  Application throws an exception and the record is lost.

What event can I intercept, or what function do I need to override to do pre-navigation validation of my form's data and cancel navigation if the data is invalid in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Windows Form can handle [FormClosing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) where in you can put your validation code. The FormClosing Event has FormClosingEventArgs object, so if any of your validation fails, you can set its Cancel property to True to prevent navigating away.

**EDIT**

For a form that uses BindingNavigator object, you should be able to handle its "Validating" Event to achieve similar effect. In your BindingNavigator's Validating EventHandler, just set the Cancel Argument for its CancelEventArgs object, in case any of your validation(s) fail(s).

Comment: That solves the issue with saving data content (with validation to cancel) for a form showing a single record with no navigation - a straight "enter your data here" form.  What I have is a form showing one record at a time from a table with a navigation control allowing the user to scroll through records in the database table and make whatever edits are required - similar to what our users are used to with Access forms linked to tables.  I need to be able to validate the data entry (and save edits to the database) before allowing them to navigate away from the current record.

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't get back earlier. I have edited the answer to include your requirement.

Comment: if anyone else has the issue I had - the validating event never fired for bindingnavigator..
The control does not display the property int he designer, but you can still set it : bindingnavigator.CausesValidation = true;
I do this in the form load.

this alone still won't do it.
you also need to set the focus.
bindingnavigator.focus();
I do this in the bindingnavigator_ItemClicked event so it happens no matter what button is clicked.

i now have validation being called!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a datagridview object to present the values, you will need to handle the RowValidating Event

Comment: Not using DataGridView at all unfortunately.  I have a DataBindingNavigator and a collection of controls with data binding to fields in my data source.

Comment: For code reuse, if you have many forms where you would want to do validations, you might want to consider using Validation Application Block: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650131.aspx

Comment: Thanks Arun, that looks like interesting reading.  I suspect that it is a little more in-depth than is required for my current issue, and doesn't solve my immediate problem.  My validation requirements are very simple at this point - I just need to check for null values in required fields, but I can't find where I can do this to prevent the user from trying to navigate away from the page.

Comment: Got it. Going to post another answer (with hyperlinks)